# php opcache caches output

Tags: php, opcache

I recently enabled Zend opcache on my server.
but there is a problem here.
when i edit a file and save that , the edited file not showing recent changes and shows previous data.
for example my file before edit is :

```
<?php
echo 'no Edit';
?>
```

then i edit this file:

```
<?php
die('Edited');
echo 'no Edit';
?>
```

if opcache enabled, When i run , I get `no Edit` as output.
(even if i clear all file data)

if opcache disbled, there's no problem.

Comment: And we should help you with what?

Comment: Is it nature of opcache ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.because in `opcache_get_configuration()` :

`[opcache.revalidate_freq] => 60`